# Ticker object has no attribute 'stats' yfinance related issue

Tags: python, trading, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance, yfinance

This is the error im getting.
" AttributeError: 'Ticker' object has no attribute 'stats' "

Im assuming it either hasnt had asset.stats() created for it to access or store
['price']['regularMarketPrice']

or related to yfinance's tickers.tickers issue not being assessable?
[Accessing yfinance Ticker objects for multiple tickers results in AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63253364/accessing-yfinance-ticker-objects-for-multiple-tickers-results-in-attributeerror)

could someone help answer this please or lead me in the right direction?
Thank you :) (my first post here)

code is from https://pyquantnews.gumroad.com/l/46-page-ultimate-guide-pricing-options-implied-volatility-python-pdf-code-pyquant-news

```
def option_chains(ticker):
    """
    """
    asset = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    expirations = asset.options
    
    last_price = asset.stats()['price']['regularMarketPrice']
    
    chains = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for expiration in expirations:
        # tuple of two dataframes
        opt = asset.option_chain(expiration)
        
        calls = opt.calls
        calls['OptionType'] = "call"
        
        puts = opt.puts
        puts['OptionType'] = "put"
        
        chain = pd.concat([calls, puts])
        chain['Expiration'] = pd.to_datetime(expiration, utc=True)
        
        chains = pd.concat([chains, chain])
    
    chains['UnderlyingSymbol'] = ticker
    chains['UnderlyingPrice'] = last_price
    
    return chains
```

```
# define a Options object
options_obj = option_chains(underlying_symbol)

# let's pickle the dataframe so we don't have to hit the network every time
options_obj.to_pickle('options_frame.pickle')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
\The_46-Page_Ultimate_Guide_to_Pricing_Options_and_Implied_Volatility_With_Python_PDF__code__live_options_data.ipynb Cell 44 line 2
      1 # define a Options object
----> 2 options_obj = option_chains(underlying_symbol)
      4 # let's pickle the dataframe so we don't have to hit the network every time
      5 options_obj.to_pickle('options_frame.pickle')

\The_46-Page_Ultimate_Guide_to_Pricing_Options_and_Implied_Volatility_With_Python_PDF__code__live_options_data.ipynb Cell 44 line 7
      4 asset = yf.Ticker(ticker)
      5 expirations = asset.options
----> 7 last_price = asset.stats()['price']['regularMarketPrice']
      9 chains = pd.DataFrame()
     11 for expiration in expirations:
     12     # tuple of two dataframes

AttributeError: 'Ticker' object has no attribute 'stats'
```

I tried changing the asset = yf.Ticker(ticker) to yf.Tickers(tickers)
yf.Ticker(ticker)

on the second block of code options_obj = option_chains(underlying_symbol)
underlying_symbol was originally "aapl" ive changed it to ticker "DVN".

All other charts show/plot DVN information.

I was expecting it to store the options information I think.